# Huge #sql-xxxx-xxxx.ibd files in mysql-data folder

Tags: mysql, temp

mysql version 5.7.28

When I tried to run optimize table, my database crashed. It left this 100G file #sql-ib3480-1658766754 in the mysql data dir. When I run show tables, the table doesn't show up. I have tried the solution proposed here (https://serverfault.com/questions/364391/huge-sql-xxxx-xxxx-ibd-files-in-mysql-data-folder). The drop table

```
drop table `#mysql50##sql-ib3480-1658766754`
```

I get a message "ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'historic_moogdb.#mysql50##sql-ib3480-1658766754'"

I use percona backup utility to backup my database. Even that backs up that file.

Any other ideas to get rid of this file.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the file system and delete the file.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` is almost never needed for InnoDB tables.

If you did a huge delete from the table, let's discuss better ways to do *that* task: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig